# How to fetch the current run status (i.e. success or failure) of all metronome jobs?

Tags: dcos, metronome

We are using metronome, and we want to create a dashboard for our jobs scheduled by it against its [rest API](https://dcos.github.io/metronome/docs/generated/api.html).

Alas, the job endpoint

```
/v1/jobs
```

does not contain the last state, i.e. success or failure, but only its configuration.

Googling on how to get the history of a job, I found out that I can query the job history through [`embed=history` GET parameter for each `jobId`](https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/browse/DCOS-529).

I could now combine fetching the id list so that I could then fetch each job's history through:

```
 /v1/jobs/{job_id}?embed=history
```

Yet this includes all the runs and also requires us to fetch each job individually.

Is there a way to get the metronome job status without querying all the jobs one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can click on each `GET` or `POST` endpoint on the official docs to see if it supports additional query params.

The endpoint for jobs [indeed supports historic data](https://dcos.github.io/metronome/docs/generated/api.html#v1_jobs_get)

[image: Metronome]

As you can see you can use `embed=history` or `embed=historySummary`, for your use-case `embed=historySummary` is better suited as it only contains the timestamps of the last run in this form and is less expensive and time-consuming:

```
[
{
    "id": "your_job_id",
    "historySummary": {
        "failureCount": 6, 
        "lastFailureAt": "2018-01-26T12:18:46.406+0000", 
        "lastSuccessAt": "2018-04-19T13:50:14.132+0000", 
        "successCount": 226
    }, 
    ...
 },
 ...
 ]
```

You can compare those dates to figure out if the last run was successful. Yet keep in mind that `lastFailureAt` and `lastSuccessAt` might be `null` as a job might have been never run in the first place:

```
  {
    "id": "job-that-never-ran",
    "labels": {},
    "run": {
    ...
    }
    "historySummary": {
      "successCount": 0,
      "failureCount": 0,
      "lastSuccessAt": null,
      "lastFailureAt": null
    }
  },
```